# Apache Redirect folder to subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

A client had an application at `www.example.com/dir`. They have now set up a subdomain at `dir.example.com`. The subdomain references the files stored at `www.example.com/dir`. They'd now like people accessing `www.example.com/dir` to be redirected to `dir.example.com`.

I'm guessing I need a `.htaccess` to sit in `www.example.com/dir` and if it's accessed with www, redirect to the subdomain, just not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 8):

What about simply:

```
Redirect /dir http://dir.example.com
```

Comment: This should be correct answer.

Comment: Use `RedirectPermanent` (or `Redirect 301` or `Redirect permanent`) instead for a 301 redirect (as opposed to a 302 - temporary).

Answer (score 7):

Add a `.htaccess` to the directory belonging to `www.example.com/dir`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://dir.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

The first line enables `mod_rewrite`, the second line checks that the current request is using hostname `www.example.com` to access the resource, and the third line redirects all such requests to the desired target hostname.

Comment: [R] yields 302 Moved Temporarily. You may want to use [R=301] to get 301 Moved Permanently.

Comment: Do it the 302 way until you're sure it's working, then switch to the 301.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule in a .htaccess file in your */dir* directory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=dir.example.com
RewriteRule .* http://dir.example.com/$0 [L,R=301]
```

Or this rule in your root directory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=dir.example.com
RewriteRule ^dir(/(.*))?$ http://dir.example.com/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

djhowell was almost there:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/dir(/.*)?$ http://dir.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

You need the leading slash in the `RewriteRule` or nothing will match. The `(/.*)?$` bit means match 0 or 1 slash-then-anything chunks to the end of the URI. (This is important -- without it we'd also match `www.example.com/dirsomethingelse`).

- `www.example.com/dir -> dir.example.com`
- `www.example.com/dir/ -> dir.example.com/`
- `www.example.com/dir/blah.html -> dir.example.com/blah.html`

Comment: @earl had the .htaccess *inside* the /dir folder, so it basically does the same. (Except for making the `www.`-part optional.)

Comment: Yep, didn't notice that. We seldom use .htaccess so I'm always thinking of the main configuration file.

Comment: Using `.htaccess` in this case saves you the trouble of having to match `/dir/` explicitly.

Comment: "You need the leading slash in the `RewriteRule` or nothing will match." - This is only if the directives are being used in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context. The OP is suggesting the use of `.htaccess` (_directory_ context) - in this case the leading slash should be omitted.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^dir/(.*) http://dir.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Additional explanation is required. This won't work if it was to be used in the `.htaccess` inside the `/dir` subdirectory as suggested in the question. If you include the `dir/` in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ then it will need to go in the `.htaccess` file in the _document root_.